# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError?

Tags: java, kotlin, ubuntu, android-jetpack-compose, compose-desktop

I'm trying build simple desktop application compose and in my normal kotlin code try something like:

```
fun main() = Window {
    Text("kotlin compose!!")
}
```

So when I make run to code, I got this Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void androidx.compose.desktop.AppWindow_desktopKt.Window-BIDTD-Q$default(java.lang.String, long, long, boolean, java.awt.image.BufferedImage, androidx.compose.ui.window.v1.MenuBar, boolean, boolean, androidx.compose.desktop.WindowEvents, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0, kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0, int, java.lang.Object)'
```

To be honest code like this work fine when I use Default desktop compose project,
But I trying in normal kotlin project in this time.

OS: Ubuntu 20.10
INV: Intellij Idea 2021.1

Comment: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError` usually indicates a wrong version of the class in the classpath. Check the version(s) of the corresponding dependency, most probably you'll find a conflict of versions there.